# Multiple download on single action not working in my webview app

Tags: java, android, webview, download

I'm trying to download multiple files in a single action, but it's not working.

My code:

```
var links =[
  "https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/Minecraft.exe",
  "https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/Minecraft.dmg",
  "https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/Minecraft.jar"];

function downloadAll(urls) {  
  var link = document.createElement("a");  
  link.setAttribute("download", null); 
  link.style.display = "none";  
  document.body.appendChild(link);

  for (var i = 0; i<urls.length; i++) {
    link.setAttribute("href", urls[i]);
    link.click();
  }

  document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="downloadAll(window.links)">Test me!</button>
```

Comment: When you say "no working", what do you mean? What happens, or doesn't?

Comment: when i click the button nothing happens at all

Comment: Its Working In Android chrome But not Working In Android Webview app